# ElasticSearch ignores similarity setting

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set `DFR` similarity for one of my index fields, as detailed [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-similarity.html). The setting is ignored, however.

When I set `BM25`, it works:

```
"properties": {
  "foo": {
    "type": "string",
    "similarity": "BM25" 
  }
}
```

A `GET` request to the index reports the similarity setting. The exact same request with `DFR` is ignored:

```
"properties": {
  "foo": {
    "type": "string",
    "similarity": "DFR" 
  }
}
```

And a `GET` request to the index reports the default similarity in use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this out, seems to be related: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15345

Comment: What version of ES are you using? I tried on 2.4 and 1.4 and I do not see any issues.